# Deploy java socket application using AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sockets, cloud

I'm currently coding a java music client-server using sockets, and i would like to deploy my project in a cloud service like AWS. But most of the tutorials out there talking about Spring web apps and lack in explanation. Im stuck for days in this. Is there any well-explaining website, a course or a youtube video that shows how to roll the whole process?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question and is probably something a google search is better for. Simply typing in "deploy java server sockets aws" in Google seems to have quite a few non Spring Boot related results. My guess is you'll need an EC2 instance of some sort if that helps. Perhaps more details of specific requirements your app needs would be useful in order to better determine which AWS products you need a tutorial for.